# Left join ON condition AND other condition syntax in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine's querybuilder in Symfony2 to create a query to fetch entities.

My current code looks like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AaaBundle:Application');

    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->addSelect('i')
        ->orderBy('a.created_date', 'DESC')
        ->leftJoin('a.created_by', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('a.installations', 'i')
        //->where('i.page = :page')
        //->setParameter('page', $found)
        ;
```

Now I can use this to get all the pages regardless of them having an installation or not.
But I only want to join them it the `$found` page is available (so that if there is an installation for the app, but it's on another page, the installation wont be joined). If I unquote the where clause, it will show only apps that have an installation for the page. I want all apps with or without installations for the page.

In SQL I can get this by adding `AND` to the join

```
LEFT JOIN installations i ON a.id = i.app AND i.page = :page
```

This way I get the installation info for an app that has an installation on the page, but I get null values on the columns for app's that have installations on other pages or not at all.

Is there a way to do this in Doctrine or am I better off just getting all the installations for each application and then checking against the found page with php?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can try this :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;

->leftJoin('a.installations', 'i', Expr\Join::WITH, 'i.page = :page')
->setParameter('page', $page)
```

See function leftJoin in doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Comment: I'm using DQL instead, and the WITH keyword can be used there as well, right after the join clause.

Comment: You can lean even more on the query builder like this.


`->leftJoin('a.installations', 'i', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('i.page', ':page'))->setParameter('page', $page);`

Comment: For accuracy purpose : "Expr\join" comes from "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr"

Comment: @DavidBaucum What benefit is there to using the expression API?

Comment: @JacobThomason it allows you to craft a customer `ON` clause for joining two entities. This is usually not needed, but in special circumstances it can be useful.

Comment: @DavidBaucum pretty sure I can just write that in DQL without all the extra syntax.

Comment: Yes, if you are righting in DQL, and not relying on the Query Builder, then that's definitely doable.