# Join table using two columns of the tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have mysql query

```
 SELECT `users`.`user_id`,  `tool`.`name` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN 
`project` ON
    `users`.`user_id` = `project`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `tools` ON `users`.'user_id' = `tools`.`user_id` AND `project`.`project_id` = `tools`.`project_id`
    Where project_id = value
    and user_id = value
```

and my doctrine query is this

```
    $query = $queryBuilder->select ( array (
                'user.userId',
                'user.name',

            ))
            ->from('Users', 'users')
    ->leftJoin(user.project, project)
    ->leftJoin(user.tool, tool)
    ->where(user.userId = value)
    ->andWhere(project.projectId = value)
```

now how would i include the  **AND `project`.`project_id` = `tools`.`project_id**
part to Doctrine query builder
without

Comment: Most probably you have wrong database model, the relation between tables `tool` and `user` is redundant and should not be there. Also, do you  really want left joins ? How do your entities look like ?

Comment: I think this question answers yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185587/left-join-on-condition-and-other-condition-syntax-in-doctrine
Use the 'WITH' keyword.