# Doctrine QueryBuilder - CASE WHEN

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a question about case when in doctrine.
The problem with this is when `uim.isProfileImage is` 1 for a user, that returns that row and every other row in `user_image` table for that user.
What I want is, if there is a profile image (`isProfileImage` is 1 in `user_image` table, there can be only one row with that value for same user) give me only that row, and if there isn't something like that give me null for that.

```php
public function searchUsersByIds(array $ids)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
    $qb->select('user.id', 'user.username');
    $qb->addSelect('(CASE WHEN uim.isProfileImage = :isProfileImage THEН uim.imageFileName ELSE :null END) AS imageFileName');
    $qb->leftJoin('user.userImages','uim');
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('user.id', ':ids'));
    $qb->setParameter('ids', $ids);
    $qb->setParameter('isProfileImage', 1);
    $qb->setParameter('null', null);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

So it should look something like this:
With profile image:

```
userId => 1,
username => 'Mark',
imageFileName => 'someFileName'
```

And without profile image:

```
userId => 1,
username => 'Mark',
imageFileName => null
```

Also since there is an in expr, it should work with multiple ids that pass to this function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may want to use a join with a condition:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185587/left-join-on-condition-and-other-condition-syntax-in-doctrine

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked, but I used the solution from down there. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
public function searchUsersByIds(array $ids)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
    $qb->select('user.id', 'user.username');
    $qb->addSelect('uim.imageFileName AS imageFileName');
    $qb->leftJoin('user.userImages','uim', 'with', 'uim.isProfileImage = :isProfileImage');
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('user.id', ':ids'));
    $qb->setParameter('ids', $ids);
    $qb->setParameter('isProfileImage', 1);
    $qb->setParameter('null', null);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time. :D