# left join Doctrine query

Tags: php, sql, join, doctrine-orm

I have 2 table that I want to join with doctrine left join. I want the result to show every user on my "User table" even when score table doesn't have user data on it. 
And I want it to still show every user when I query other months.

My "User table" as main table

```
 userid | username | usergroup
------------------------------
   1    | AAAA     |    A
   2    | BBBB     |    A
   3    | CCCC     |    B
   4    | DDDD     |    C
```

And this is my "Score table" to join with "User table"

```
 scoreid | userid | month | game1 | game2 
-----------------------------------------
   1     |   1    |   1   |   80  |  80   
   2     |   1    |   2   |   60  |  90
   3     |   3    |   1   |   80  |  70
```

I want it to look like this when I choose for `usergroup` = A and with `month` = 1

```
 username | game1 | game2 
---------------------------
   AAAA   |  80   |  80   
   BBBB   |  NULL |  NULL
```

This is what I have done so far. this is not my actual doctrine code.

```
->select('u.username','s.game1','s.game2')
->from('xxxxxxx:User', 'u')
->leftJoin('xxxxxxx:Score', 's', 'WITH', 'u.userid = s.userid')
->where('u.usergroup = :group')
->andWhere('s.month = :month OR s.month is NULL')
```

the problem is When I trying to query again with for example `month`= 2 the query result is empty or not showing all the user from "User table", since I only filter for equal month or when its NULL.
How to make a query so I could still be able to query every user for every month?

any help would be very appreciated. thanks

Comment: This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087933/how-to-do-left-join-in-doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks to Prava for the link. so i come up with this to solve the problem.

```
->select('u.username','s.game1','s.game2')
->from('xxxxxxx:User', 'u')
->leftJoin('xxxxxxx:Score', 's', 'WITH', 'u.userid = s.userid AND s.month =:month')
->where('u.usergroup = :group')
```