# How to get a multidimensional array as a result from a joined query? (Doctrine2)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I would like to create a query with `join` using `queryBuilder`. I would like to get the result from it in a multidimensional array, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15088250/3042117

Unfortunately I get just one dimensional array as a result. Like `[UserCrediHistory,UserInstance,UserCreditHistory,UserInstanc‌​e....]`

How to get the result in this format?

```php
array(
    array(
        0 => UserCreditHistory instance,
        1 => Userinstance,
    ),
    array(
        0 => UserCreditHistory instance,
        1 => Userinstance,
    ),
    // ...
)
```

---

My code looks like this:

```
$qb->select(array('ow', 'us', 'it'))

->from('\\Entities\\MyItem', 'it')

->innerJoin(
    '\\Entities\\User',
    'us',
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
    'it.user = us.id'
)
->innerJoin(
    '\\Entities\\User',
    'cr',
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
    'it.owner = ow.id'
);
```

---

I tried to change the hydration mode, or call `getArrayResult()`, but it's still the same