# Left join in doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need to fetch data from 2 tables. Actually just need to include one field from 2nd table into result of 1st table on basis of form key.

I did research and find a way to do this.

```
$qb->select(array('a', 'c'))
   ->from('Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article', 'a')
   ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'c');
```

When i implemented it, it shows error 
Error: Class  has no association named comments which is obvious thing because comments is not a field of Article table (entity). I am confused how to define 2nd table from which field needs to fetched, as a.comments is relates of Article table.

Comment: can you show us your entities?

Comment: entity names or entities code?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer but I believe [this question can help you answer yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087933/how-to-do-left-join-in-doctrine).

Comment: entities code where you have the relation with comment

Comment: Do you have any relation between these 2 entities ? One to many or many to many ?

Comment: NO, i want to do it without association.

Answer (score 2):

To use `Doctrine`'s joins you must tell `Doctrine` what is the relation between your entities. This is done using the relationship annotations (`@OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany`) that you can find in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

**You can't use joins without associations in Doctrine.**

According to your question, I assume that your Article entity has a `OneToMany` relationship with Comments. Then, your entities definition should be similar to:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Article{
     //.... all your current fields
     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
      */
     private $comments;
     //.... setters and getters
} 

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Comment{
     //.... all your current fields
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")
      */
     private $article;
     //.... setters and getters
}
```

Using these entities you'll be able to execute the query.