# How to join by the discriminator column in Symfony with Doctrine DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a Symfony 4 project and I'm using Doctrine DQL in my repositories to grab data from the database.

I have 4 tables: Initiatives, Organisations, Users and Permissions.

Initiatives table:

```php
id, name, description
```

Organisations table:

```php
id, name, description
```

Users table:

```php
id, first_name, last_name
```

Permissions table:

```php
@int initiative_id - foreign key for Initiatives table 
@string reference - the discriminator column. Can have 'organisation' OR 'user' as a value 
@int reference_id - the ID of the Organisation OR User
```

so **Organisations** and **Users** are the Entities in the discriminator column.

I want to select **only** the records where the discriminator column has the values **organisation** and together with the organisation details from the organisations table.

The select statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT i, ip, o FROM Entity:Initiative i
JOIN i.permissions ip
JOIN ip.organisation o
WHERE ip INSTANCE OF Entity:OrganisationPermission
```

If I run it will show the error:

```php
InitiativePermission has no association named organisation
```

**InitiativePermission** being the entity class for the **permissions** table.

**JOIN ip.organisation o** is the problem here....and is normal to see this error because of course we don't have an **organization** column in **permissions** table...we have a **reference** and **reference_id** which can be organisations or user.

How can I JOIN with the **organization** table by the **reference** (discriminator) column ?

Can I do this with DQL or I need another solution ?

Comment: Can't do it with DQL.  The discriminator column in internal to Doctrine and not exposed to the developer.  You could add a second column with the same value or you could drop down and use sql via the DBAL layer.

Comment: I think the only solution I have here is to go with your suggestion, add a 2nd column, one for each entity.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Working with Associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) in the docs? You can do what you're after with a `->matching($criteria)` statement on a Collectoin result. So, if `->getUsers(): Collection`, you can `$this->getUsers()->matching($criteria)`. Also, please don't use  `discriminator` like you are, in Doctrine it has [another meaning](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#querying-inherited-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "**no relation join**" with the Organisation entity:

```
SELECT i, ip, o FROM Entity:Initiative i
JOIN i.permissions ip
LEFT JOIN Entity:Organisation o WITH o.id = ip.referenceId
WHERE ip INSTANCE OF Entity:OrganisationPermission
```

This way you get only Organisation entities joined.
You do not need the discriminator column in this case.

[How to do left join in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087933/how-to-do-left-join-in-doctrine)

Comment: Your solution is good but the result I get is not formatted as I need it. I will probably have to go with 2 separate columns, one for Users and one for Organisations instead of one Reference column.